# System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already

Tags: c#, api, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, invalidoperationexception

I have an Api deployed on Azure in which I have a `CrCart` entity. I want to make sure that if there is already a cart associated with a user and a customer with the status "Saved" you can't add more with that status.

The issue here is that I make that validation on my Post method on my `CrCart` Service and it works fine but on my Put method it doesn't.

Here is the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'CrCart' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using...
```

Here is the code for both my `Insert` and `Update` methods:

```
public async Task Insert(CrCart cart)
        {
            var user = await _unitOfWork.CrUserRepository.GetById(cart.IdUser);
            var customer = await _unitOfWork.CrCustomerRepository.GetById(cart.IdCustomer);

            var carts = _unitOfWork.CrCartRepository.GetAll();
            carts = carts.Where(x => x.IdCustomer == cart.IdCustomer && x.Status == "Saved" && x.IdUser == cart.IdUser);

            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new BusinessException("El usuario introducido no existe");
            }

            if (customer == null)
            {
                throw new BusinessException("El cliente introducido no existe");
            }

            if (carts.Count() >= 1 && cart.Status == "Saved") {

                throw new BusinessException("Ya existe un carrito con estado -Saved- asignado al cliente " +
                    customer.Name);
            }   

            await _unitOfWork.CrCartRepository.Insert(cart);
            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task<bool> Update(CrCart cart)
        {
            var user = await _unitOfWork.CrUserRepository.GetById(cart.IdUser);
            var customer = await _unitOfWork.CrCustomerRepository.GetById(cart.IdCustomer);

            var carts = _unitOfWork.CrCartRepository.GetAll();
            carts = carts.Where(x => x.IdCustomer == cart.IdCustomer && x.Status == "Saved" && x.IdUser == cart.IdUser);

            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new BusinessException("El usuario introducido no existe");
            }

            if (customer == null)
            {
                throw new BusinessException("El cliente introducido no existe");
            }

            if (carts.Count() >= 1 && cart.Status == "Saved")
            {

                throw new BusinessException("Ya existe un carrito con estado -Saved- asignado al cliente " +
                    customer.Name);
            }

            _unitOfWork.CrCartRepository.Update(cart);
            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

            return true;

        }
```

I already have my service Scopped so that's not the issue. Please help because I don't know what it is causing this and I have a deadline for this project. Thanks.

**EDIT**

My `BaseRepository` in which I have generic methods

```
 public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T: BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly db_crijoyaContext _context;
        protected readonly DbSet<T> _entities;

        public BaseRepository(db_crijoyaContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _entities = context.Set<T>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
           return _entities.AsEnumerable();
        }

        public async Task<T> GetById(int id)
        {
            return await _entities.FindAsync(id);
        }

        public async Task Insert(T entity)
        {
            await _entities.AddAsync(entity);
            
            //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            
            _entities.Update(entity);
            
            //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task Delete(int id)
        {
            T entity = await GetById(id);
            _entities.Remove(entity);

            //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        }

    }
```

And my `UnitOfWork` where I have all the repositories

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork 
    {
        private readonly db_crijoyaContext _context;
        private readonly ICrProductRepository _productRepsitory;
        private readonly IBaseRepository<CrCompany> _companyRepository;
        private readonly IBaseRepository<CrCategory> _categoryRepository;
        private readonly IBaseRepository<CrCart> _cartRepository;
        private readonly IBaseRepository<CrCustomer> _customerRepository;
        private readonly IBaseRepository<CrUser> _userRepository;
        private readonly IBaseRepository<CrOrder> _orderRepository;
        private readonly IBaseRepository<CrCity> _cityRepository;
        private readonly ICrUserInfoRepository _userInfoRepository;
        private readonly ICrCountryRepository _countryRepository;

        public UnitOfWork(db_crijoyaContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public ICrProductRepository CrProductRepository => _productRepsitory ?? new CrProductRepository(_context);
        public IBaseRepository<CrCategory> CrCategoryRepository => _categoryRepository ?? new BaseRepository<CrCategory>(_context);
        public IBaseRepository<CrCompany> CrCompanyRepository => _companyRepository ?? new BaseRepository<CrCompany>(_context);
        public IBaseRepository<CrUser> CrUserRepository => _userRepository ?? new BaseRepository<CrUser>(_context);
        public IBaseRepository<CrCart> CrCartRepository => _cartRepository ?? new BaseRepository<CrCart>(_context);
        public IBaseRepository<CrCustomer> CrCustomerRepository => _customerRepository ?? new BaseRepository<CrCustomer>(_context);
        public IBaseRepository<CrOrder> CrOrderRepository => _orderRepository ?? new BaseRepository<CrOrder>(_context);
        public IBaseRepository<CrCity> CrCityRepository => _cityRepository ?? new BaseRepository<CrCity>(_context);
        public ICrUserInfoRepository CrUserInfoRepository => _userInfoRepository ?? new CrUserInfoRepository(_context);
        public ICrCountryRepository CrCountryRepository => _countryRepository ?? new CrCountryRepository(_context);

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if(_context != null)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's the working code which I don't know if it is done properly

```
public async Task<bool> Update(CrCart cart)
        {
            var user = await _unitOfWork.CrUserRepository.GetById(cart.IdUser);
            var customer = await _unitOfWork.CrCustomerRepository.GetById(cart.IdCustomer);

            var carts = _unitOfWork.CrCartRepository.GetAllWithNoTracking();
            carts = carts.Where(x => x.IdCustomer == cart.IdCustomer && x.Status == "Saved" && x.IdUser == cart.IdUser);

            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new BusinessException("El usuario introducido no existe");
            }

            if (customer == null)
            {
                throw new BusinessException("El cliente introducido no existe");
            }

            if (carts.Count() >= 1 && cart.Status == "Saved")
            {

                throw new BusinessException("Ya existe un carrito con estado -Saved- asignado al cliente " +
                    customer.Name);
            }

             _unitOfWork.CrCartRepository.Update(cart);
            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

            return true;

        }

public IEnumerable<T> GetAllWithNoTracking()
        {
            return _entities.AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable();
        }
```

Comment: are you 100% sure, that you don't update current entity somewhere else at the same time?

Comment: @hamaronooo I am sure as it works if I delete the `carts` List, so If I delete the validation I want to do it works

Comment: may it be that you load the same entity twice, like in case of linked entity to another entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes if you use `async` methods with entities without `await` or waiting, and before your first `async` task finished, you started to call another task, it will throw this `exception`.

So, in addition, you should use `AsNoTracking()` method with entities you will not change and then will not save (just read).

**UPDATE 1:**
In the end of your code check this lines:

```
_unitOfWork.CrCartRepository.Update(cart);
await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Maybe you need to add `await` before `_unitOfWork.CrCartRepository.Update(cart);`

**UPDATE 2:**

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllWithNoTracking()
{
   return _entities.AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable();
}

public async Task<T?> GetByIdWithNoTracking(int id)
{
    return await _entities.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
}
```

or you can replace it with `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()` if you have newest EF CORE.

**UPDATE 3**
Also try this:

```
_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I have read about that method but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to use it

Comment: @robluc check last update please

Comment: It will give an error as I am calling my Update method on my `CrCartRepository` which is located on my `UnitOfWork` and it is a void method

Comment: @robluc can you provide the code of Update method?

Comment: I've edited the post so you can see

Comment: @robluc Check Update 2

Comment: I'm going to try this thanks!

Comment: @robluc Be warn, in UPDATE 2 you need to find entity without AsNoTracking before update it.

Comment: So, it works by adding the `GetAllWithNoTracking` method and calling it in my `carts` list where I check if the cart exists but I don't know if I'm doing correctly

Comment: I'm going to add the code that is working now in case something is missing because I don't know if I understood correctly your comment where you said that I need to find the entity before updating it

Comment: @robluc are your entity can be saved after you use AsNoTracking?

Comment: I left my code just as it was but using now the AsNoTracking method. I get the cart object as a parameter and I update it after I call `GetAllWithNoTracking` to display an error if it finds the object